# R: ggplot2 axis shows two ranges

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am using a ggplot with facet_wrap() like below:

```
plot <- ggplot(x, aes(Result, values, fill=Month))+
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position=position_dodge())

plot + facet_wrap(~Month)
```

My plot is like below:
[image]

As you see, the plot shows two different ranges for the months.

dput(x) is:

```
structure(list(Result = structure(c(2L, 1L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("Negative", 
"Positive"), class = "factor"), values = c("100", "0", "66.6666666666667", 
"33.3333333333333"), Month = structure(c(2L, 2L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("January", 
"February"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

How do i fix this?

Comment: Looks like `values` variable is a factor and not a numeric data type, hence the unexpected y axis that is out of numeric order.

Comment: Please, provide a [mcve]. In particular, please, post the contents of `x` using `dput(x)` or show the result of `str(x)`. Thank you.

Comment: @Uwe Ive added the dput(x) value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `values` was coerced into a factor at some point, with the levels `0, 100, 33.33, 66.66`. I'm able to replicate the plot using the following code:

```r
df <- tibble(result = c("neg", "pos", "neg", "pos"),
             values = factor(c(33.33, 66.66, 0, 100),
                             levels = c(0, 100, 33.33, 66.66)
                             ),
             month = factor(c("jan", "jan", "feb", "feb"),
                            levels = c("jan", "feb")
                            )
             )

ggplot(df, aes(result, values, fill=month)) +
    geom_bar(stat="identity", position=position_dodge()) + 
    facet_wrap(~ month)
```

[image]

You just need to convert `values` back into a numeric vector. Just be careful that the integer representation of the levels isn't returned instead of the numbers you want, i.e. do something like `as.numeric(as.character(values))` and not `as.numeric(values)`:

```r
df %>% mutate(values = as.numeric(as.character(values))) %>% 
    ggplot(aes(result, values, fill=month)) +
    geom_bar(stat="identity", position=position_dodge()) + 
    facet_wrap(~ month)
```

[image]